# Running multiple monitors with different generations of ATI cards

Tags: multiple-monitors, gpu, amd-radeon, ati-mobility-radeon, dual-gpu

So the situation is that I currently have an HD4850, that is running two monitors. I'm looking to buy an HD7850 to run my two other monitors. Is it possible to mix the HD4XXX and HD7XXX generations of cards to run multiple monitors?

Comment: You could when both generations were supported by the same driver.

Comment: @Ramhound How do I know if both generations were supported by the same driver?

Comment: AMD publishes that information.

Comment: the latest AMD driver doesn't support support the HD4XXX serires any longer. But AMD publishes a legay driver for those old cards.